# fglrx does not have /usr/lib/libGL.so lib

Tags: software-installation, 10.10, fglrx

I am trying to compile some OpenGL apps from source, but there is no `/usr/lib/libGL.so`, or `/usr/lib/libGL.so.1` or even `/usr/lib/libGL.so.1.2`, however fglrxinfo says:

```
display: :0.0  screen: 0
OpenGL vendor string: ATI Technologies Inc.
OpenGL renderer string: ATI Mobility Radeon HD 4500 Series
OpenGL version string: 3.3.10237 Compatibility Profile Context
```

Which is what I expect and the gears demo also works.

How do I get those files? I tried the MESA files and then I got software rendering which is not what I wanted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `libgl1-dev` package is a meta-package that contains the required lib and can be replaced with software implementations `libgl1-mesa-swx11` or dri accelerated version `libgl1-mesa-dri`.

Answer (score -1):

The *fglrx* package contains /usr/lib/fglrx/libGL.so

To see which libs glxgears (or any other program) is using use

```
ldd "$(which glxgears)"
```

Comment: I could do that but it would make my binaries to link only against the libs on my machine, if i run those on a intel or nvidia environment it would not work.